# Checking if two arrays are equal: returns incorrect result

Tags: c#, arrays

I am trying to check if two arrays of equal size contain the same integers at the same indexes. If some element are not equal I want to return `true`, and otherwise return `false`.

```
public bool multipleSolutions(int[,] grid)
{
    int[,] front = new int[9, 9];
    front = grid;
    int[,] back = new int[9, 9];
    back = grid;
    front = solve(front);
    back = solveBackwards(back);
    for (int r = 0; r < 9; r++)
    {
        for (int c = 0; c < 9; c++)
        {
            if (back[r, c] != front[r, c])
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

When tested separately, `solve` and `solveBackwards` give two different arrays, but when I try `multipleSolutions` it still gives me `false` (since they are two different arrays, I want it to return `true`).

Comment: Why are you not using `int[,] front = solve(grid); int[,] back = solveBackwards(grid);` to start with? That would be simpler. In particular, those new arrays you create are pointless. Do those methods modify the arrays that are passed in? It's hard to help you without knowing what those methods do. A short but complete program demonstrating the problem would be ideal.

Comment: Add a break point after the `solveBackwards` call and manually check the arrays.

Comment: As long as all arrays are `[9,9]` the loops in the `for{for{}}` looks OK. So your error is in some part of the code that was not posted.

Comment: "Do those methods modify the arrays that are passed in?" The modify them inside the functions, does that change the array outside of the function aswell?

Comment: there's only a single array - `grid`. You create two new arrays at the top of your function but then immediately make them garbage with your assignments of `front = grid` and `back = grid` - those lines don't *copy* grid - they just make `front` and `back` reference the same array that `grid` is referencing.

Comment: Okay, how do i Copy them instead of refernce them?

Comment: @kopp: See my answer below on how to copy the data in the arrays.

Comment: @Tafari: It leaves the loop at the first item that *doesn't* match, so that is perfectly fine. It only goes on to return `false` if all items match.

Comment: @Guffa you are right! My mistake. Deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the test logic is correct the most likely cause to this error is that the implementation of `solve` and `solvebackwards` changes the array passed in and returns the same array.

For both the call to solve and to solveBackwards the array identified by the parameter grid is passed in. So if solve changes the passed-in array then the input for solveBackwards has been changed accoring to the first run. Which might affect solveBackwards. The result wouldn't differ though because under th above assumption when solveBackwards is done. both front and back would then be the result of the solveBackwards

**assumptions**

- solve and solveBackwards alters the array passed in
- the return value of solve and solveBacrwards are the array passed in

**EDIT**
Seeing the the assumptions are correct you could insert this as the first line in both solve and solveBackwards

```
var temp = new int[9,9]
Array.Copy(grid, 0, temp, 0, grid.Length);
```

and then use temp through the implementation of solve and solvebackwards.

Alternatively you could do the same for front and back before passing them in as an argument

however you should then change the return type of the two methods. Specifying a return type is indicative of returning a different object and not mutating the argument. This is also why I'd prefer the first option (copying the array inside the method)

However even better in my opinion would be to iterate the input array and constructing an inemurable with the result

Comment: Yes that is exactly my problem. How can I get a new duplicate of grid so I can send solve and solvebackwards a unique copy of the original grid?

Comment: @HenkHolterman why? it's an attempt to solve the most likely cause to the problem and even though the most likely cause is lack of understanding of the runtime it doesn't make it an off topic question. The problem is described in enough details to make it possible to give an answer with a high possibility of solveing the problem

Comment: You can't use `ToArray` on a two dimensional array.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that you put the `grid` array in both the `front` and `back` variables. When you assing an array to an array variable, it doesn't copy the data from one array to another, it copies the reference to the array object. All your references will end up pointing to the same array object.

To copy the data from one array to another you can use the `Copy` method:

```
int[,] front = new int[9, 9];
Array.Copy(grid, front, grid.Length);
int[,] back = new int[9, 9];
Array.Copy(grid, back, grid.Length);
```

Now you have two new array objects that contain the data from the original grid.

Comment: I didn't down vote but i would expect that it could be because you left out one rather important detail. It doesn't matter if grid is apssed in to both solve and solveBackwards as long as `solve` copies the array and returns the copy

Comment: but seeing that my answer also got a DW and does indeed include that assumption, it might be something else :)

Comment: @RuneFS: Perhaps the reason, but then the downvote is unfair, as the OP specifically stated in a comment to the question that the arrays are changed in the methods.